# java streams: easiest way to find adjacent value match

Tags: java, java-stream

How would it be possible to convert this iterative block of code to streams?

```
Integer prev = -1;
boolean adjacentPair = false;

for(Integer num : numberList) {
    if (num.equals(prev)) {
        adjacentNumberSame = true;
        break;
    }
    prev = num;
}
return adjacentNumberSame
```

Comment: Why use streams? This is simple and fast. The stream might be slower.

Comment: You know advent of code right? So I'm moving all my solutions in iterative to java streams, to strenghten my understanding of streams and what can I do with them. I know streams might not be faster, but solving simple solutions in streams will help to address problems on higher level afterwards.

Comment: `to strenghten my understanding of streams` - Yes it's nice to practice a lot at first. But keep in my mind that `stream` is not always better than a `for`. Here for example, the `for` is easy to understand and straightforward, the `stream` is bulky and hard to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one (not so great) way to do it:

```java
IntStream.range(1, numberList.size())
         .anyMatch(i -> numberList.get(i).equals(numberList.get(i-1)));
```

If your `numberList` is an `ArrayList` or something similar its complexity is acceptable. If not, you'd better use `iterator`. Like so:

```java
var Iter = list.stream().iterator();
var res = list.stream()
              .skip(1)
              .map(v -> v.equals(Iter.next()) )
              .anyMatch(v -> v)
              ;
```

More elegant ways require some third-party libraries with a `zip` function. With `zip` it can look like:

```java
var res = zip(
              list.stream().skip(1),
              list.stream(),
              (a, b) -> a.equals(b)
          ).anyMatch(x->x);
```

Or you can write your own `zip`. Something like this:

```java
public static <A,B,C> Stream<C> zip(Stream<A> listA, Stream<B> listB, BiFunction<A,B,C> zipper){
    var iB = listB.iterator();
    return listA.filter( a -> iB.hasNext())
                .map( a -> zipper.apply(a, iB.next()) );
}
```

PS. I would not recommend `reduce` as it used in @vbezhenar's answer. Because it will not shortcircuit, as you can see here https://repl.it/repls/DisastrousWideRevisioncontrol (look for exception)

Comment: i see  usage of the anyMatch solution for the code very intuitive. At least for the Integer list. Thanks for gong extra effort to provide code snipped for zipper. It will be good reference for same solution seekers. Thx x00!

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce operation. Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3);
    class Result {
        boolean adjacentPair = false;
        Integer prevItem = null;
    }
    boolean adjacentPair = list.stream().reduce(new Result(),
            (result, item) -> {
                result.adjacentPair = result.adjacentPair || item.equals(result.prevItem);
                result.prevItem = item;
                return result;
            },
            (result1, result2) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
    ).adjacentPair;
    System.out.println(adjacentPair);
}
```

class `Result` holds intermediate result. `adjacentPair` field indicates whether adjacent pair has been encountered. `prevItem` field holds value of the previous item which is compared on the next iteration. Third argument to this function is combiner, it's used for parallel streams and this example works with serial streams.

Comment: quite original approach, I did thought reducing could solve, but did not knew exactly how. This is good example of solution, espacially when problem expands to something bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all of that. Implement this for the body of your method:

```
return numberList.contains(prev);
```

For example, you could have:

```
public boolean adjacentNumberIsSame(int currentValue, ArrayList<Integer> numberList){
    return numberList.contains(currentValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. this is fine in case I would like to find an occurrence in the list. Here we want to check only if adjacent value match. So in your example we get True if First matches Last value. Opposite of what Pseudocode tries to check.

Comment: @tjago you will need to pass in a list containing adjacent values. You should be splitting up the creation of the adjacent values list and the checking of the values into two different methods..

Answer (score 1):

Streams aren't the way to go. This is quite a general statement.

A particular problem here is that **you cannot *fold and short-circuit***.

The *streamy solution* I came up with was similar to @vbezhenar, except it is well behaved (has the combiner) and doesn't introduce an accumulator class.

```
    // Accumulator is: { leftElement, match, rightElement }
    //    (Could introduce a record.)
    // States of the accumulator are:
    //    { null null null } - initial
    //    { x null x } - first element
    //    { x m null } - found match m
    //    { x null y } - no matches found
    Integer[] result = numberList.stream().<Integer[]>collect(
        // supplier
        () -> new Integer[3],
        // accumulator
        (acc,t) -> {
            if (acc[0] == null) {
                // First into acc.
                acc[0] = acc[2] = t;
            } else if (acc[1] != null) {
                // Already found pair to the left.
            } else if (t.equals(acc[2])) {
                // Found first pair.
                acc[1] = t;
                acc[2] = null;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, t replaces rightmost.
                acc[2] = t;
            }
        },
        // combiner
        (acc, other) -> {
            if (acc[1] != null) {
                // Alread found pair to the left.
            } else if (acc[2] == null) {
                // Necessary anyone? Empty acc is combined.
                acc[0] = other[0];
                acc[1] = other[1];
                acc[2] = other[2];
            } else if (acc[2].equals(other[0])) {
                // Found match.
                acc[1] = acc[2];
                acc[2] = null;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, leftmost element with rest as other acc.
                acc[1] = other[1];
                acc[2] = other[2];
            }
        }
    );
    return result[1] != null;
```

I haven't actually tested the combiner. I suspect **most combiners have never been tested** either.

If we make similar assumptions about stream behaviour as @vbezhenar did, then `dropWhile` is our Johnny 5 friend.

```
    return numberList.stream().dropWhile(new Predicate<>() {
        Integer last;
        public boolean test(Integer t) {
            Integer lastLast = last;
            last = t;
            return !t.equals(lastLast);
        }
    }).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Anonymous inner classes ftw!!